# iMac Debian 11 (Intel) - crackling sounds, poor quality sound

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, macintosh, intel

I've installed Debian on my iMac (from late 2013) which has Intel chipset. Currently I am trying to solve a sound problem, which probably was here since the system is installed. The sound can be played, however from time to time I hear some crackling from the speakers. For example, sometimes while booting, sometimes while switching off the system, and when I open the Audacity (which I installed after I discovered the problem). Additionally, when I play music, the quality of the sound is poor, sounds like a cheap radio or worn out old car speaker (or low compression). When I boot to MacOS that is also installed on this iMac, the sound quality is much better.
The audio device is: **8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller**

I tried to install newer kernel 5.15 (from backports), however I came back to the previous one 5.10 (from stable repo) by using the Timeshift. The problem was still there. Updating the kernel didn't solve the issue.
I tried all the solution from this PulseAudio page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/PositionReporting however with no results.

It looks like the problem existed some time ago. However I couldn't find any working solution.

After typing in terminal *pacmd list-cards* I have these results:

```
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xb1080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0e0a"
        device.product.name = "GK104 HDMI Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "GK104 HDMI Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb1d10000 irq 57"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8c20"
        device.product.name = "8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5565, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-ac3-surround-51: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output (priority 300, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 365, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
```

After typing in: *cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec* I get:

```
Codec: Cirrus Logic CS4206
```

Comment: After doing some extra testing, I found out that when I plug headphones, I hear no audio. I also installed VLC, and in preferences I set audio output through ALSA directly to the Analog front output. However the sound quality stayed the same bad as with default PulseAudio output. Again I booted to macOS and the sound quality there is way better. What might be causing this in Debian?

Comment: I found an interesting thread on one of Linux forums about improving audio quality in Linux (https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-terrible-sound-in-linux-much-better-in-windows/8203/6), it's about passing some settings to the daemon.conf PulseAudio file. However after passing these settings on my Debian, I can't hear significant improvement :/. Music on macOS is very nice and in the settings there is set only: 44.1kHz, 24 bits, integer, 2 channels.

Comment: I found a solution for the large part of the problem, I installed PulseEffects and manually added: Bass Amplifier, Crystalizer, Exciter and Limiter at the end. I set my own settings and now the sound is much better, at least now I can listen to some music. However crackling still exists. At the moment I am still testing some settings with PulseEffects. Later I may write my solution to the question, however it is not 100% solved (let's say 70-80%). Is the sound on MacOS better because it uses some built-in effects to correct the sound, so it can be well matched for iMac speakers?